# What does a typecast at the beginning of an arithmetic expression apply to?

Tags: c++, c, casting

I don't understand how a typecast can sit at the beginning of a binary arithmetic expression. Does it typecast both variables or only one?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int sum = 17, count = 5;
    double mean = (double) sum / count;
    printf("Value of mean : %f\n", mean );
}
```

Is it casting `(double) (sum / count)` or only `((double) sum) / count`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is parsed as `((double) sum) / count`. Casting one of the operands is a common trick to force floating-point division. `int / int` would use integral division which truncates the decimal portion. `double / int` forces the second operand to be coerced into a `double` as well, resulting in `double / double` which doesn't truncate.

Notice that if it were parsed as `(double) (sum / count)` it would *not* work. This would still perform integer division, truncate the decimal portion, and *then* cast that result to a double. The cast would come too late.

When in doubt, consult [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). Their [operator precedence chart](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) shows that C-style casts have higher precedence than division:

> The following table lists the precedence and associativity of C++ operators. Operators are listed top to bottom, in descending precedence.
>
> [image: operator precedence chart]

Answer (score 2):

The typecast operator has higher precedence than the division operator.  So this:

```
(double) sum / count
```

Parses as this:

```
((double) sum) / count
```

Meaning that `sum` is typecast to a `double`.  Then, because one operand to `/` has type `double` and the other has type `int`, The `int` operand is converted to `double` as per the *usual arithmetic conversions* and floating point division is performed.